# I am finding it difficult to understand the difference between functions in an object and functions outside the object

Tags: javascript

when I call all the functions they seem to return the same result, what is the actual difference.

```
let obme = {
  a: 'Mus',
  b: 3,
  met: function (){
    console.log(obme.a, obme.b);
  }
}
//code 1
obme.met();

//code 2
function met () {
  console.log(obme.a, obme.b);
}
met()
```

Comment: you use dot (.) operator to invoke one but not for the other

Comment: looking at the scope, why do I need to add the function inside the object. sorry if my question sounds dumb.

Comment: They return the same result because both are looking at `obme.a` and `obme.b`.  Why would you expect different results?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Okay does that mean I can choose to define my function outside an object and there won't be a time when I need to define it inside the object. I was actually thinking they could return the same result but mean different thing or have different use case.

Comment: @AminuBarade It really depends what you are doing.  You don't _need_ to declare anything anywhere, but it might make more sense to have the function as a part of the object so it doesn't clutter your code with functions you don't need.  Or if you pass the object into another function/scope, or something like that.

Comment: @AminuBarade If you declare the function inside the object, then you can use `this.a` and `this.b` instead of `obme.a`/`obme.b`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ooh Alright, I understand thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, functions are first-class. This means that a function can be stored in a variable just as easily as a string, number, or other "typical" value:

```js
let a = 5
//> a is 5

let a = function() { alert('hello world!') }
//> a is a function
```

Javascript also supports some parts of the common object-oriented paradigm. So, it is sometimes meaningful to refer to a function as a *method* instead of just a function. All methods are functions, but not all functions are methods.

Very loosely, whether a routine is best-described as a "method" or a "function" depends on two things: (1) whether the routine is attached to something; and (2) whether the routine *actually cares* about that something. If it is not attached to anything, but is a free-floating function, then it's not a method. Methods are sometimes described as "stateful functions," which is another way of saying that it cares about stuff other than its arguments.

You have a function implementation, which you've attached to the plain object `obme` by storing it in the named property `met`. Very importantly, while this routine *does* care about data on the `obme` object, it's hard-coded to care about a specific instance stored in a specific variable, rather than caring about whatever instance it is attached to.

Here is an example of an object that has two routines, one a method and one just a function:

```js
let obme = {
  name: 'Fido',
  some_function: function() { return 'Fido' },
  some_method: function() { return this.name }
}
```

Both routines get called the same way:

```js
obme.some_function()
//> 'Fido'

obme.some_method()
//> 'Fido'
```

The difference is that `some_function` will *always* return 'Fido', whereas `some_method` will return whatever value is stored in the `name` property of the object it lives on:

```js
obme.name = 'Changed name'

obme.some_function()
//> still says 'Fido'

obme.some_method()
//> 'Changed name'
```

Now compare that to this:

```js
function another_function() {
    return this.name
}
```

That won't return "Fido", even though the implementation is identical to `some_method`. The reason is that `another_function` is not attached to anything that can serve as `this`.<sup>1</sup>

Any function can refer to `this`. And if you need, you can explicitly set `this` for any function invocation by using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), or [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
let temporaryHostObject = {
    name: 'Apollo'
}

obme.some_method.call( temporaryHostObject )
//> 'Apollo'
```

In other OO languages, the definitions of "function" and "method" are less flexible, but in Javascript it's very common to collect a bunch of free-floating functions into a single top-level object, despite the fact that those functions do not actually care about the object they are attached to (or even about each other). This kind of resembles static methods in typical OO languages, except that doing this in javascript doesn't depend on (or take into account) any kind of inheritance.

People will quibble over terms (and I expect I'll take some flak for my offered definitions), but the basics about functions in JS are straightforward:

1. you can store a function anywhere you can store other data
2. functions that are stored on objects can be accessed using dot notation just like any other property (e.g. `thing.nestedThing.functionName()`)
3. whether the function cares about being attached to something depends on what's inside the function
4. you can tell the function to act like a method on any specific object by using `apply`, `call`, or `bind` to explicitly provide the `this` value

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In browsers, `this` in free functions resolves to the global `window`. In other environments, like Node, `this` may refer to other values. We can ignore this detail for now. It is always a terrible idea to use `this` to refer to the window; if you want the window, say `window`.</sup>